# Error in object avoiding robot arduino code

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I wanted to build an object avoiding robot and copied this store from pastebin. Now when I upload the code I get an error like this.
Arduino: 1.8.13 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Uno"

C:\Users\Pranay\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Arduino_New_Ping-master\src\NewPing.cpp:35:16: warning: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'begin' with no type [-fpermissive]

NewPing::begin() {

^

C:\Users\Pranay\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Arduino_New_Ping-master\src\NewPing.cpp:35:1: error: prototype for 'int NewPing::begin()' does not match any in class 'NewPing'

NewPing::begin() {

^~~~~~~

In file included from C:\Users\Pranay\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Arduino_New_Ping-master\src\NewPing.cpp:8:0:

C:\Users\Pranay\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Arduino_New_Ping-master\src\NewPing.h:213:10: error: candidate is: void NewPing::begin()

void begin();

^~~~~

exit status 1

Error compiling for board Arduino Uno.

Invalid library found in C:\Users\Pranay\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ARDUINO_OBSTACLE_AVOIDING_CAR: no headers files (.h) found in C:\Users\Pranay\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ARDUINO_OBSTACLE_AVOIDING_CAR

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.

```
// Before uploading the code you have to install the necessary library//
//AFMotor Library https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-motor-shield/library-install //
//NewPing Library https://github.com/eliteio/Arduino_New_Ping.git // 
//Servo Library https://github.com/arduino-libraries/Servo.git //
 
#include <AFMotor.h>  
#include <NewPing.h>
#include <Servo.h> 
 
#define TRIG_PIN A0 
#define ECHO_PIN A1
#define MAX_DISTANCE 100 
#define MAX_SPEED 150 // sets speed of DC  motors
#define MAX_SPEED_OFFSET 20
 
 
NewPing sonar(TRIG_PIN, ECHO_PIN, MAX_DISTANCE); 
 
AF_DCMotor motor1(1, MOTOR12_64KHZ); 
AF_DCMotor motor2(2, MOTOR12_64KHZ);
AF_DCMotor motor3(3, MOTOR34_64KHZ);
AF_DCMotor motor4(4, MOTOR34_64KHZ);
Servo myservo;   
 
boolean goesForward=false;
int distance = 100;
int speedSet = 0;
 
void setup() {
 
  myservo.attach(10);  
  myservo.write(115); 
  delay(2000);
  distance = readPing();
  delay(100);
  distance = readPing();
  delay(100);
  distance = readPing();
  delay(100);
  distance = readPing();
  delay(100);
}
 
void loop() {
 int distanceR = 0;
 int distanceL = 0;
 delay(40);
 
 if(distance<=25)
 {
  moveStop();
  delay(100);
  moveBackward();
  delay(200);
  moveStop();
  delay(200);
  distanceR = lookRight();
  delay(200);
  distanceL = lookLeft();
  delay(200);
 
  if(distanceR>=distanceL)
  {
    turnRight();
    moveStop();
  } 
 
  else
 
  {
    turnLeft();
    moveStop();
  }
 } 
 
 else
 {
  moveForward();
 }
 distance = readPing();
}
 
int lookRight()
{
    myservo.write(50); 
    delay(500);
    int distance = readPing();
    delay(100);
    myservo.write(115); 
    return distance;
}
 
int lookLeft()
{
    myservo.write(170); 
    delay(500);
    int distance = readPing();
    delay(100);
    myservo.write(115); 
    return distance;
    delay(100);
}
 
int readPing() { 
  delay(100);
  int cm = sonar.ping_cm();
  if(cm==0)
  {
    cm = 250;
  }
  return cm;
}
 
void moveStop() {
  motor1.run(RELEASE); 
  motor2.run(RELEASE);
  motor3.run(RELEASE);
  motor4.run(RELEASE);
  } 
 
void moveForward() {
 
 if(!goesForward)
  {
    goesForward=true;
    motor1.run(FORWARD);      
    motor2.run(FORWARD);
    motor3.run(FORWARD); 
    motor4.run(FORWARD);     
   for (speedSet = 0; speedSet < MAX_SPEED; speedSet +=2) // slowly bring the speed up to avoid loading down the batteries too quickly
   {
    motor1.setSpeed(speedSet);
    motor2.setSpeed(speedSet);
    motor3.setSpeed(speedSet);
    motor4.setSpeed(speedSet);
    delay(5);
   }
  }
}
 
void moveBackward() {
    goesForward=false;
    motor1.run(BACKWARD);      
    motor2.run(BACKWARD);
    motor3.run(BACKWARD);
    motor4.run(BACKWARD);  
  for (speedSet = 0; speedSet < MAX_SPEED; speedSet +=2) // slowly bring the speed up to avoid loading down the batteries too quickly
  {
    motor1.setSpeed(speedSet);
    motor2.setSpeed(speedSet);
    motor3.setSpeed(speedSet);
    motor4.setSpeed(speedSet);
    delay(5);
  }
}  
 
void turnRight() {
  motor1.run(FORWARD);
  motor2.run(FORWARD);
  motor3.run(BACKWARD);
  motor4.run(BACKWARD);     
  delay(500);
  motor1.run(FORWARD);      
  motor2.run(FORWARD);
  motor3.run(FORWARD);
  motor4.run(FORWARD);      
} 
 
void turnLeft() {
  motor1.run(BACKWARD);     
  motor2.run(BACKWARD);  
  motor3.run(FORWARD);
  motor4.run(FORWARD);   
  delay(500);
  motor1.run(FORWARD);     
  motor2.run(FORWARD);
  motor3.run(FORWARD);
  motor4.run(FORWARD);
    }
I had installed the servo library new ping library and motor shield library can any one of you please identify what is wrong here please
```

Comment: You may want to download the NewPing library from the link on [Arduino Playground](https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/NewPing/). The version you downloaded from the github has a bug on `NewPing::begin()`.

Comment: ok thx i will try

Comment: t worked thanks a lot